# Routing network traffic on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, networking, routing, 3g

I have two network adapters. One is connected to a 3g-router and the second network adapter is connected to the local network.

I want to route all traffic on specific ip-addresses/hosts to the 3g-router using the "route add"-command and the rest should use the local connection.

Both connections work on their own but when they are enabled together neither of them work as expected, not even when one is set to a higher metric. Both are set up as "Private-networks".

All requests time-out. When I add a route to the 3g-router, tracing it works but surfing wont.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vista supports only one internet connection, and in addition has the annoying habit of always preferring wired connections over non-wired, on the supposition that they are faster (have better metric).

See this article for a solution with many screenshots :
["Windows Vista Multiple Networks: Wireless To Public WIFI and Wired To Private LAN"](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/10/29/windows-vista-multiple-networks-wireless-to-public-wifi-and-wired-to-private-lan/).

The basic solution is to use the command:

> route delete 0.0.0.0 IF 11

where the IF 11 refers to Inteface List # 11 (which is displayed by route print command output, in the Interface List section). Replace 11 by the number of the interface that you **don't** want to use for surfing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add more details. I needed to route local `10.*` requests to the ethernet adapter and every other request (internet) to wifi adapter. This is what I did:

1. Find out gateway IP of the ethernet adapter using `ipconfig`. My was `10.0.150.1`
2. Find out ethernet adapter number using `route print`. My was `11`
3. `route delete 0.0.0.0 IF 11`
4. `route add 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.0.150.1`

This way every LAN request routed through LAN adapter.

Comment: If I were to "disable" the WiFi bit will internet traffic then revert to the LAN side? I am trying to avoid Internet via LAN as it has silly filters on it but I don't want to download large files over 4G, so I will just enable and disable the 4G as I need it.